# In combination problems, when does distinguishability of objects matter?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If I have $n$ objects, and asked the number of ways to choose $k$ of them, the answer is $\binom{n}{k}$ ([example problem 1](https://imgur.com/a/MpD0oJW)). Similarly if I have $n$ objects and asked to put $a$ in one bin, $b$ in another, and $c$ in another, I think the number of ways I can do this is $\frac{n!}{a!b!c!}$ ([example problem 2](https://imgur.com/a/UudvoV1)). I'm sure but I don’t think the answer changes whether the objects are, say, all the same (color) or are partially or completely distinct, despite the fact that if the objects are identical the combinations “look” the same (unless there's some other way to tell the objects apart that isn't explicitly stated).

However, in a stars and bars problems, the objects are indistinguishable but the bins are, so in this case the distinguish-ability matters. How do I identify when having distinguishable objects matter and when not?

Answer (score 2):

It always matters whether thinks are distinguishable.  In your first example, if the $n$ items are identical there is only one way to select $k$ of them, not $n \choose k$.  Similarly in your second example there would be only one way if the objects were identical.  In a typical stars and bars problem the objects are not distinguishable, but if they were there would be many more ways to put them in the bins.

Sometimes it is difficult to determine whether the objects are distinguishable or not, but that is a different question.

Comment: In the first example problems I linked, the [solution](https://imgur.com/a/pChkGnv) to the problem states that there are $\binom{n}{j}$ ways of choosing balls j balls out of n balls of a one color (and $\binom{n}{n-j}$ ways of choosing n-j balls out of n balls of the other color). Are the balls actually all distinguishable in this case? Similarly, in the second problem I linked, is it implied that the three objects (wins, loss, ties) all individually distinguishable?

Comment: Yes, they must be.  If you have five identical balls in a bin and choose three, you can't tell which three they are so there is only one way.  In your problem, the colors group the balls into two groups of $n$, but they assume the red balls are all still distinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

It changes the answers if it matters. We care about distinguishable states in combinatorics. Here are just **some** of the possibilities for combinations.

1. combinations without repetition (distinguishable)
2. combinations with repetition (indistiguishable elements)
3. combinations with replacement (indistinguishable elements)
4. combinations without replacement(see 1 and 2)
5. combinations with restriction (ex. alice and bob next to each other in a class photo)

For permutations we have the nearly the same, and much more ( different answers though).

For the first above, think of three students Alice,Bob, and Charlie. Lets pick 2, we can pick any of the three for the first person and any of the remaining 2 for the second. We also don't care in this case (indeed most cases in combinations) about the order they are picked. So we get: $$\frac{3\cdot\not2}{\not2}=3$$ possible choices: $$\{(Alice,Bob),(Alice,Charlie),(Bob,Charlie)\}$$

For the second above, what if Charlie was a Bob, then the two Bob's can't be distinguished by name (Hello need for surnames and nicknames). In this case we have 2 choices total $$\{(Alice,Bob),(Bob,Bob)\}$$ We don't care about which Bob it is, we can't tell the difference. No name in each pair represents the same person twice, so Both Bob's are in the second one.

The third one above, is like drawing names but putting the names back each time a name is drawn. We care about how many times each name was drawn, not the order.

The fourth one above, has the first 2 as subtypes.

The fifth above, has better examples such as combinations with **exactly** 3 even numbers.

Comment: In the three student example with two Bobs (or in something more complicated like 9 balls, 2 of which are indistinguishable and we are asked to number of ways to choose 8 of them), how to we express the result in terms of binomial coefficients?

Comment: $\binom{8}{8}+\binom{7}{1}$ I believe. Pick all 8 distinguishable, or pick both indistinguishable but pick 1 of the 7 remaining to be left out)

Comment: Is there a general rule on how to select from n objects in which only k < n are distinct, a < k of the n objects? I assume if a >= k the answer would just be one?

Comment: it can get complicated it depends on the quantity chosen and number of indistinguishable item subsets that are used etc. for example. in permutations on a chess piece set for one person there are 16! permutation of pieces but all 8 pawns can take on any permutation and not tell the difference, same with 2 knights, bishops,rooks, so you actually have only $$\frac{16!}{8!2!2!2!}=64,864,800$$ distinguishable orderings of all piece of one side versus 20,922,789,888,000 if taken to be distinguishable.